# HBase is not working in Hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to install hbase-0.96.0-hadoop2 on Hadoop 2.2.0. While I am trying to start my HBase. HBase is giving following error.

master: log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.DRFAS
master: log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "DRFAS".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.DRFAS
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "DRFAS".

When I am doing JPS Linux is showing following processes:

17422 JobHistoryServer
11461 NameNode
31375 Jps
12127 ResourceManager
11671 DataNode
30077 HRegionServer
12344 NodeManager
11935 SecondaryNameNode
30948 HQuorumPeer

Here is my **hbase-site.xml** configuraiton:

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000/hbase</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are
      false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed Zookeeper
      true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh)
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>master</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/master</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: are you trying to install new hbase 0.96.x or migrating from older version ie 0.94x.

Comment: @user3202540 - I placed the log4j.properties file from v0.94x in v0.98x, and the error seemed to go away, looks like some tweaking is required in log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these two methods .

1. Stop your hbase demon and clear the hbase log files which was located
   in /tmp/ folder delete all files which had name hbase in it
2. after deleting disconnect your machine from internet and try to
   start the hbase demon now.

Hbase has this weird issue in some x64 ubuntu  machines disconnecting from internet will help in resolving this issue,after startup you can connect to the internet.

now try to access hbase from cli

```
bin/hbase
```